# Choose an answer from a list of item suggestions on the search bar using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created a search bar with element suggestion after typing words.
I would like here after the display of the list of suggestions that I can click on a result and that it is positioned on the input.

script.js

```
const articles = [
{name:'matoss'},
{name:'solution'},
{name:'moloss'},
{name:'KARKAN'}
];

const rechercheInput=document.getElementById('rechercheInput');
rechercheInput.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
const input = rechercheInput.value;
const result = 
articles.filter(item=>item.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input.toLocaleLowerCase()));
let suggestion ='';

if(input != ''){
    result.forEach(resultItem =>
        suggestion += `<div class="suggestion">${resultItem.name}</div>`
        )
}
document.getElementById('suggestions').innerHTML=suggestion;
})
```

index.html

```
<form method="get" action="">
   <input type="search" name="recherche" placeholder="code article.." id="rechercheInput" 
required>
   <div id="suggestions"></div>
   <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Recherche
   <i class="material-icons right">search</i>
   </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe datalist can help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: what is the problem you are having with your code? does it throw errors?

Comment: if we use dataList , then it is possible not to use javaScript?

Comment: @codageStarter , 
no, there's no error in the code, I'm just going to add it after the result suggestion on the bar, so that I can click on the result and it is positioned on the input

Comment: @Pathia Nato yes, but then the datalist stays static

Comment: i would like to do it using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet does exactly what you described with JavaScript.

```js
const articles = [{
    name: 'matoss'
  },
  {
    name: 'solution'
  },
  {
    name: 'moloss'
  },
  {
    name: 'KARKAN'
  }
];

// DOM element handles
const input = document.getElementById('rechercheInput')
const suggestions = document.getElementById('suggestions')
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')

// handling form submit
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // only for the snippet - you might not need this
})

// utils
const toLowerCase = (s) => s.toLowerCase()
const strIncludes = (s1) => (s2) => s1.includes(s2)
const filterByName = (val) => ({
  name
}) => strIncludes(toLowerCase(name))(toLowerCase(val))

// emptying a DOM element (#suggestions)
const empty = (element) => {
  while (element.firstElementChild) {
    element.firstElementChild.remove();
  }
}

// getting the items from the possible articles
const getFilteredArray = (arr) => (keyword) => keyword ? arr.filter(filterByName(keyword)) : []
const getFilteredArticles = getFilteredArray(articles)

// input event handler
input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const filteredArticles = getFilteredArticles(e.target.value)
  updateSuggestions(suggestions, this)(filteredArticles)
})

// creating suggestion item DOM element
const getSuggestionItemEl = (suggestion) => {
  const suggestionItem = document.createElement('div')
  suggestionItem.classList.add('suggestion-item')
  suggestionItem.textContent = suggestion.name
  return {
    suggestionItem,
  }
}

// base for handling click on suggestion items
const getListenerFn = (input, article, callback) => (e) => {
  input.value = article.name

  if (callback && callback instanceof Function) {
    // if a callback function is defined, then it's called with
    // the following args
    callback(input)
  }
}

// updating the suggestions list
const updateSuggestions = (container, input) => (filteredArticles) => {
  // 1. emptying the container
  empty(container)

  // 2. generating the DOM elements; adding click handler;
  // adding generated elements to the container (#suggestions)
  filteredArticles.forEach((article) => {
    const {
      suggestionItem
    } = getSuggestionItemEl(article)
    suggestionItem.addEventListener('click', getListenerFn(input, article, (input) => updateSuggestions(container, input)(getFilteredArticles(input.value))))
    container.append(suggestionItem)
  })
}
```

```css
.suggestion-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.suggestion-item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
  <input type="search" name="recherche" placeholder="code article.." id="rechercheInput" required>
  <button id="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Recherche
   <i class="material-icons right">search</i>
   </button>
  <div id="suggestions"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I used your code, for css code, I place it after the js code or before??

Comment: @PathiaNanto technically it makes no difference; but usually on a webpage CSS is added in the `head` section, while JS is either at the end of `body` or in the `head` with a `defer` keyword -> this means that CSS comes before JS

Comment: using the code, on the list of suggestions I can't get the cursor to point a suggestionItem

Comment: @PathiaNanto sorry, this information doesn't really help in finding out why that could happen. you can see that in the snippet it works just fine - so there must be something in your case that's different.